# Get ALL data from getifaddrs()

Tags: c, linux

I see example for getifaddrs()
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html#EXAMPLE

They ignore all interfaces that don't have ifa_addr

```
if (ifa->ifa_addr == NULL)
               continue;
```

I've checked and all that skipped interfaces have ifa_data that is not NULL. What is hidden there? What should I cast ifa_data to?

Comment: Check the NOTES section in that man page

Comment: Does it mean that if ifa_data is not NULL then it is always rtnl_link_stats?

Comment: From what I can gather from [the code](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/ifaddrs.c;h=0594afeecf37f9b8c366759f2d57f24ba6183d4e;hb=HEAD#l317) yes - but since noone documented how it works, who knows !